# С Realloc не работает как надо

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

typedef struct 
{
    int id;
    int val;
} strow;

typedef struct
{
    int id;
    char* title;
} dbrow;

const int ALLOC_SIZE = 4096;

int dbindex = 0;
int dbsize = 0;
int dballoc = 0;

dbrow  *DBS = NULL;
dbrow  *DBSTEMP = NULL;

int stindex = 0;
int stsize = 0;
int stalloc  = 0;

strow *STAT = NULL;
strow *STAT_TEMP = NULL;

static void load_st_row( char * s)
{
    int n = 0;
    char * ptr2 = NULL;
    ptr2 = s;

    char * tok = strchr( ptr2, '|' );
    while( tok )
    {
        *tok = 0;
        switch (n) {
               case 0:
                      if (atoi(ptr2)==0) {
                         return;
                      }
                      stindex = atoi(ptr2);
                      while (stindex >= stalloc) {
                         stalloc = stalloc + ALLOC_SIZE;
                         STAT_TEMP = (strow *) realloc(STAT, (stalloc+1) * sizeof (strow));
                         if (STAT_TEMP == NULL) {
                            free(STAT);
                            printf("Not enough memory for stat\n");
                            return ;
                         }
                         STAT = STAT_TEMP;
                      }
                      STAT[stindex].id = stindex;
                      STAT[stindex].val = 0;
                    break;
               case 1:STAT[stindex].val = atoi(ptr2);break;
        }
        ptr2 = tok + 1;        
        tok = strchr( ptr2, '|' );
        n++;
    }

    if (*ptr2) 
    {
        switch (n) {
               case 1:STAT[stindex].val = atoi(ptr2);break;
        }
    }
}

static void load_dbs_row( char * s)
{
    int n = 0;
    char * ptr1;
    ptr1 = s;

    char * tok = strchr( ptr1, '|' );
    while( tok )
    {
        *tok = 0;
        switch (n) {
               case 0:
                      if (atoi(ptr1) == 0) {
                         return ;
                      }
                      dbindex = atoi(ptr1);
                      while (dbindex >= dballoc) {
                         dballoc = dballoc + ALLOC_SIZE;
                         DBSTEMP = (dbrow *) realloc(DBS, (dballoc+1) * sizeof (dbrow));
                         if (DBSTEMP == NULL) {
                            free(DBS);
                            printf("Not enough memory for db\n");
                            return ;
                         }
                         DBS = DBSTEMP;
                      }
                      DBS[dbindex].id = dbindex;
                    break;
               case 1:DBS[dbindex].title = ptr1;break;
        }
        ptr1 = tok + 1;        
        tok = strchr( ptr1, '|' );
        n++;
    }

    if (*ptr1) 
    {
        switch (n) {
               case 1:DBS[dbindex].title = ptr1;break;                
        }
    }

}

int main()
{
    int i,a;
    char * newline;
    char * ptr;
    char *content = NULL;
    content = (char *)malloc(50);
    strcpy (content,"1|raz\n11|dva\n21|tri\n31|shestb\n5000|test\n|||\n||\n|\n");    
    ptr = content;

    newline = strchr( ptr, '\n' );
    while( newline )
    {
        *newline = 0;
        load_dbs_row( ptr );
        ptr = newline + 1;
        newline = strchr( ptr, '\n' );
        dbsize++;
    }
    if( *ptr )
    {
        load_dbs_row( ptr );
        dbsize++;
    }

    char * stnewline;
    char * stptr;
    char *stcontent = NULL;
    stcontent = (char *)malloc(114);
    strcpy (stcontent,"12932|0|507.7139|78|15.3630|507.7139|78\n19080|0|566.1302|27|4.7692|566.1302|27\n1|0|566.1302|27|4.7692|566.1302|27");        
    stptr = stcontent;

    stnewline = strchr( stptr, '\n' );
    while( stnewline )
    {
        *stnewline = 0;
        load_st_row( stptr );
        stptr = stnewline + 1;
        stnewline = strchr( stptr, '\n' );
        stsize++;
    }
    if( *stptr )
    {
        load_st_row( stptr );
        stsize++;
    }

    printf("\nStats:\n");
    for ( i = 1; i <= stalloc; ++i ) {
        if (STAT[i].id > 0) {
           printf("sID: %d\t\tval: %d\n",STAT[i].id,STAT[i].val);
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    exit(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Два массива данных (`STAT` и `DBS`), почему то смешиваются. Если сделать константу `ALLOC_SIZE` достаточно большой, чтобы `realloc` не вызывалось, глюк пропадает.

Comment: визуально ничего плохого явно не нашел (ну кроме того, что в конце не освобождается выделенная память).
Как можно увидеть, что данные "смешиваются"?

Comment: Вот что выводит последний printf в цикле:
Stats:
sID: 1          val: 0
sID: 11         val: 4143601
sID: 21         val: 4143608
sID: 31         val: 4143615
sID: 12325376           val: 4096
sID: 12932              val: 0
sID: 19080              val: 0

Comment: у меня выводит совсем другое

    Stats:
    sID: 1  val: 0
    sID: 134929  val: 0
    sID: 102161  val: 0
    sID: 69393  val: 0
    sID: 12932  val: 0
    sID: 36625  val: 0
    sID: 19080  val: 0

Comment: дожно быть только 3 ID: 
12932
19080
1
Остальные ID непонятно откуда

мб при realloc новый блок памяти не очищиется 0ми, и отсюда мусор?

Comment: может это потому, что realloc не заполняет нулями свежо выделенную память. Поэтому, когда в цикле происходит вывод значений массива, в некоторых элементах может содержаться мусор, который вполне может остаться после первого массива.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[[@cromax](/users/12109/cromax)](/users/12109/cromax), а почему Вы решили, что они "склеиваются"?

Вот ведь индексы у Вас не подряд, и в промежутки между ними Вы ничего не пишете. С чего Вы вообще решили, что начальное состояние памяти - это нули. Там может быть все, что угодно.

--

Смотрите.

Сначала Вы делаете DBS, а потом STAT, а печатаете STAT и видя там значения DBS делаете вывод, что что-то склеилось. Распечатайте также DBS и посмотрите в нем наверняка не будет элементов STAT.

Короче. Когда Вы при создании STAT делаете один из реаллоков, то новый хвост (то, что вы **добавляете** в реаллоке) размещается на месте где **когда-то** (до очередного реаллока) размещалось **начало** DBS. При последующих реаллоках STAT эти значения, естественно, копируются вместе со всем, что и Вы в STAT писали.

Резюме.

1. Обнуляйте сами вновь добавляемую память.
2. Выбросьте while для реаллока.

Достаточно

```
  if (index >= allocated) {
    newallocated = allocated + index + ADD_SIZE;
    tmp = realloc(...);
    ...
    memset(tmp + allocated * sizeof(...), 0, (newallocated - allocated) * sizeof(...
    allocated = newallocated;
    ...
  }
```

И напишите, пожалуйста, одну функцию (с нужными параметрами) вместо двух (load_st_row и load_dbs_row) (а то, просто смотреть больно...)

Comment: спасибо за memset )
p.s. фунцию пока не могу написать, там же разные поля у структур )